Tenser's Floating Disk in an elevator
Tenser's Floating Disk floats 3 feet above the ground, or terrain, or stairs, or a slope. What happens when it's in an elevator? (or lift as the Brits call it) Will the disk move up and down as the elevator moves up and down? Will the disk help the elevator lift the heavy load on the disk?
Some DM's may ignore the explicit mention of stairs and slopes or argue that such stairs must be made of ground. Suppose instead the DM wants the disk to work in a dungeon that has many levels. Thus the floor is what the disk floats above not the floor of the lowest level of the dungeon. When the DM treats the floor of an elevator as ground, what should such a reasonable DM rule when the "ground" (surface below the disk) moves up and down?
In other words, the DM wants to go with this:


Does the ground simply mean whatever solid surface the characters and monsters are standing on?

Yes
What is "the ground"?

Given that, what happens in an elevator?

It remains three feet above the ground
If a DM defines the floor of the elevator as ground, then we know that the disk will hover over it, because the spell description says (emphasis mine):

This spell creates a circular, horizontal plane of force, 3 feet in diameter and 1 inch thick, that floats 3 feet above the ground in an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see within range

If this was all we had as the spell description, we would not know whether 'floats above the ground' meant it was dynamically three feet above 'local' ground or remained three feet above the specific ground where it was created.  Fortunately, the spell continues:

...the disk follows you so that it remains within 20 feet of you. It can move across uneven terrain, up or down stairs, slopes and the like

Thus, if the caster is moving across a change in elevation, the disk follows them laterally, and also maintains its relative position of three feet above whatever is the local elevation of the ground.  Knowing that the disk automatically responds to local changes in ground elevation, we can conclude that if the ground underneath it moved, it would maintain its three feet elevation above the (changing) ground as well.  If your DM defines the floor of the elevator as ground, the disk should be able to 'ride' the elevator, so long as its caster rides along with it.
If the disk is on the elevator and the caster is not, however, the disk would disappear once the difference in elevation became too great:

If you move more than 100 feet from the disk (typically because it can't move around an obstacle to follow you), the spell ends.

In this case, the "obstacle" the disk could not "move around" would be the floor of the elevator.  It can't get closer than three feet to the floor, so at the point that continuing to rise with the elevator would take it more than 100 feet from the caster, the spell would end.
It floats
To the question of whether the disk would help the elevator lift the load on the disk, the disk is supporting the load (of up to 500 pounds) that is suspended on itself.  This load does not impact the elevator; the elevator cannot feel the weight of anything on the disk.  Taking the common usage of the word 'float', suppose I have a 500lb weight tethered to, and suspended by, a lighter-than-air balloon.  If I drag this balloon laterally until it is over a scale, I don't see a change in the scale (unless it is so sensitive as to detect atmospheric pressure).  Similarly, anything on the disk is not impacting the force required to raise the elevator.

Good answer, but I think the bolded answer should include the following assumption - if the DM defines... Ultimately - that's the answer :)

@Wyrmwood edited, thank you


Suppose instead the DM wants the disk to work in a dungeon that has many levels. Thus the floor is what the disk floats above not the floor of the lowest level of the dungeon.  When the DM treats the floor of an elevator as ground, what should such a reasonable DM rule when the "ground" (surface below the disk) moves up and down?

If the DM does want to facilitate the disk moving in an elevator, then a reasonable ruling is that nothing exceptional happens and the disk just moves with the elevator. Like a character would. So, everything works without bogging down the game with characters having to figure out how to use an elevator efficiently.
Anything else is hardly "reasonable", in my book. If the DM wants characters to be able to use the floating disk with an elevator but then also throws in extra limitations seems like neither here nor there:

If the elevator goes down yet the disk stays where it is, then it is not convenient to use. Most likely will either stay there until the caster is out of range, then the spell ends and anything carried will fall down. Or it will move with the caster down but remain 20 feet (~6 meters) above them. Which makes reaching that equipment an issue. Overall, it will be "allowed" but annoying to deal with from in-character perspective.
If going up, then the floating disk will have to content with touching "the ground" (the lift that goes up). And any extra handling of that seems it would just be busywork for the adventurers.

Overall, any complication of using an elevator will just be a mini logistics puzzle of wolf, goat, and cabbage complexity. At best. For the characters have to figure out how to carry the equipment without a disk and using an elevator. With the only positive outcome of "Yay, we get to continue playing again".

To be clear: perhaps the groups does want to solve logistics problems like this. It is a perfectly viable campaign for players to have to focus on similar "between adventuring" problems - a game where you can win every fight but run out of food. However, this is not what the question seems to describe - it is about a DM who wants a floating disk to be usable with an elevator, therefore, a reasonable assumption is that it should not pose any additional burden.
If it really needs to (for whatever reason), it may just be abstracted away as extra time. Perhaps characters can take 5 minutes to use the elevator by themselves, or ~30 minutes (or even ~1 hour) with the disk. Abstracting away ferrying the equipment. This is a good plan if time does matter. Maybe it forces characters to make strategic decisions for what to carry if they are in a hurry. But if time is not of the essence, then the extra time is just flavour and not really useful one.
A DM may have planned each "level" of the dungeon stand-alone. Expecting adventurers will only have whatever they are equipped with to solve it. This might be a reason to bar using the floating disk in an elevator. You reach the end and can only take what you have on your character, a floating disk needs to be abandoned. This is also a valid way for a DM to handle this - just disallow elevators + floating disks. It is also not what the question describes.

Overall, the floating disk is not meant to be some sort of problem you need to solve again and again. It is a way for a magic user to have a magic-y "cart" that carries their stuff. Even from in-universe perspective, it is just a convenience spell. If wizards had to keep trying to figure out how to make the disk not get in the way when you put in in an elevator, then the spell is likely not going to be as useful for them as a horse or a donkey. Or even a literal wheelbarrow. Keep in mind, wizards are known for their towers and not known for their strength. It is reasonable to assume a very common spell (1st level) they have devised is not worse than a wheelbarrow when they need to carry stuff around.
A counter-argument (just for the sake of showing an opposed viewpoint) is that the spell is 1st level, so it is not that powerful. It may just be meant to cover 90% of the most common usages - the magic user moving on a flat-ish plane. Like a road. Perhaps the disk can handle slight inclines, as steep as stairs, but not all possible terrains. So it is worse in some cases but "good enough" for most. In which case, extra rules for handling the disk can be thrown in.
However, to focus again on the "reasonable DM rule" of "DM wants the disk to work in a dungeon that has many levels", I do not see why much else is needed. The description of the spell lays down some rules of how it moves but a "reasonable" interpretation to treat it not much differently to a character/companion who only carries stuff. Think a mule. A mule that does not need food and can disappear if too far away. But for purposes of traversal and moving, can be treated the same.

Overall, I find that a lot of times trying to throw more rules at something bogs down the game. So, I avoid doing it, when running a game. Again, this has to be measured against the type of game the group has agreed to play. But as a litmus test, consider "would trying to impose mechanics here" enhance the game or not. If not, then gloss over it (e.g., say it takes some time to do something).
Special note on rolls: I kind of see this often where it seems a GM is not sure they have to just allow their players, so they ask for a roll. This may be trying to access some knowledge from yesterday (which might be 2-3 in-world sessions/weeks ago IRL). Or maybe the GM has some information they can share with the party but ask for a roll to give it to the group. I have even seen GMs outright admit they did the roll for no particular reason. They might say something to the effect of "I did not expect all of you to fail your perception roll". Or some times it is the opposite and the GM allows a roll which they expect to fail. But it succeeds.
Never let a roll determine something you do not want to be determined by a roll. Yes, it sounds like a tautology but I keep seeing it used. The player characters somehow manage to kill the BBEG in their first encounter through enormous luck. And the GM has to now figure out what to do with their plot which called for the final confrontation in at least ten more sessions. Or the player characters utterly fail to succeed on a roll the GM expected them to pass.
Either do not call for rolls if they can go not your way, or do not plan in advance what will happen, therefore any result from a roll is expected.
In this case, do not try to do something like "Roll [something] to get the floating disc to successfully ride the elevator". Either allow or disallow it and go with that. Not much reason to impose mechanics, nor to impose rolls. The characters just randomly1 being unable to traverse an elevator with a floating disk does not sound like fun for most players. The other alternative is to roll and on "failure" it it succeeds with a cost (e.g., takes more time) but it is still random and imposes mechanics for not much to gain from employing it.
1 chosen by a fair dice roll. guaranteed to be random

"wizards are known for their towers and not known for their strength. "  True dat.

This question touches on a concept that's been debated many times in various contexts: the idea of a frame of reference. While the rules for Tenser’s Floating Disk imply a frame of reference (all spells do), they don’t explicitly define one. This is a key consideration for interpreting how the spell interacts with different environments.
Let’s explore this with a thought experiment. Imagine you’re on a moving ship and cast a spell with a persistent area of effect. Does the effect stay fixed relative to the ship or relative to the water? This question can be extended to other scenarios: Does an area of effect move with the rotation of the planet (or Toril)? What about the movement of the planet through space? Fundamentally, every point in space is described relative to a chosen frame of reference.
For Tenser’s Floating Disk, the frame of reference is critical. In the specific case of an elevator or lift:

If the frame of reference is the ground beneath the elevator, the disk would remain stationary relative to the ground. As the lift moves, the disk would lag behind, and if the range between you and the disk exceeds the spell’s limit, the disk would attempt to follow you as per the spell description. This could create a visual of the disk “chasing” the lift.
If the frame of reference is the elevator itself, the disk would move with the elevator, staying in its position relative to you.

Ask Your DM
Ultimately, the rules are silent on this, so it falls to the DM to make a ruling. It’s worth discussing this ahead of time to establish consistency, as similar scenarios may arise in other contexts. The more predictable the ruling, the smoother gameplay will be.
Good luck!
